# Reverse process of a matrix expansion on Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

My program allows to multiply a given `B` matrix with a `z` factor with some characteristics listed below, to give an `H` matrix. I would like to have a programming idea to do the **inverse** of what I programmed. That is to say with a given `H` matrix find the value of the `B` matrix.

For example with a matrix `B = [-1 -1 ; 1 0]`

I get with my code a matrix :

```
   H = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 
         0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 
         0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 
         0 1 0 1 0 0 ; 
         0 0 1 0 1 0 ; 
         1 0 0 0 0 1 ]
```

I would like to have from a code `H`  the value of the matrix `B`.

To specify the matrix `H` from the matrix `B`, it is necessary that:

Each coefficient **-1** is replaced by a **null matrix** of dimension `z*z`;

Each coefficient **0** is replaced by an **identity matrix** of dimension `z*z`;

Each coefficient `1,2,...,z-1` is replaced by a **circulating permutation matrix** of dimension `z*z` shifted by `1,2,...,z-1` position to the right.

From a matrix `B` and the expansion factors `z` , we construct an extended binary `H` matrix with `n-k` rows and `n` columns.

My code :

```
clear;
close all;

B = [-1 -1 ; 1 0];
z = 3;

H = zeros(size(B)*z);
Y = eye(z);

for X1 = 1:size(B,1)
    
    for X2 = 1:size(B,2)
        
        X3 = B(X1,X2);
        
        if (X3 > -1)
            X4 = circshift(Y,[0 X3]);
        else
            X4 = zeros(z);
        end
        Y1 = (X1-1)*z+1:X1*z;
        Y2 = (X2-1)*z+1:X2*z;
        H(Y1,Y2) = X4;
    end
end

[M,N] = size(H);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A possible solution: `B = -ones(size(H)); B(H==1) = 0;`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but if H = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0 1 0;1 0 0 0 0 1] them B = [- 1 -1 - 1 -1 - 1 -1 ; -1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 -1; -1 - 1 -1 -1 - 1 -1;-1 0 -1 0 -1 -1;-1 -1 0 -1 0 -1;0 -1 -1 -1 -1 0], which is different from the value B = [-1 -1 ; 1 0] with z = 3.

Comment: OK. I didn't considered z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all of the input matrices are well-formed, you can determine the mapping based on the first row of each block. For example, the block mapping to 1:

```
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

has a 1 in column 2 of row 1. Similarly, a one in column 1 maps to 0, and column 3 maps to 2. No ones in the row maps to -1. So we just need to find the column containing the 1 in the first row.

Annoyingly, `find` returns null when it doesn't find a nonzero value rather than 0 (which is what we would want in this case). We can adjust to this by adding a value to the matrix row that is only 1 when all of the others are 0.

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `blockproc` to handle the looping for you:

```
B = blockproc(H, [z z], @(A)find([~any(A.data(1,:)) A.data(1,:)])-2);
```

Otherwise, just loop over the blocks and apply the function to each one.

Comment: Thank you for your idea @beaker, but I really don't understand the principle. Here the "A" represents a image I guess? when I do the simulation there are some errors (BLOCKPROC encountered an error while evaluating the user-supplied function handle, FUN. The cause of the error was: Undefined function 'any' for input arguments of type 'struct'). I use Matlab 2016b with Image Processing Toolbox included.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot MATLAB passes a struct rather than an array. Please see the update.

Comment: Great, it' s working now. Very compact and ingenious method. Thank you @beaker.